# Getting error on scrolling while used tableview inside collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableview

I have added `UITableview` inside `UICollectionViewCell` with auto layout and content of table is very large. I'm getting problem while scrolling `tableView` cell to top and scroll to next `collectionView` cell. It goes up in screen. Please see attached image on which I'm suffering.

**As we can see all content jump to top**

[image]

**This is content on tableview**

[image]

Comment: you can achieve this https://i.stack.imgur.com/koSXq.png with `UITableview` only. why you are adding `UITableview` in `UICollectionview`.

Comment: @Amit I have multiple list which I need to scroll left to right and content of each item very large and dynamics that's why I used UITableview in collectionview.

Comment: it would be great to see some code